# MUI Autocomplete, where to get the array of filtered options?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a `<Divider />` underneath each option showed inside the `popper`, EXCEPT the last row. Sorry I can't post a picture, please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zduH9.png) to view a screenshot of the undesired outcome.

Here's the current code:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Autocomplete, TextField, Box, Divider } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& label, & label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "green"
  }
});

const StyledOptionBox = styled(Box)({
  color: "green"
});

const options = [
  "Company ABC",
  "Company BCD",
  "Company CDE",
  "Company DEF",
  "Company EFG",
  "Corporate ABC",
  "Corporate BCD",
  "Corporate CDE",
  "Corporate DEF",
  "Corporate EFG"
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <StyledTextField
            {...params}
            label="Search your company here"
            variant="outlined"
          />
        )}
        renderOption={(props, option) => (
          <>
            <li {...props}>
              <StyledOptionBox>{option}</StyledOptionBox>
            </li>
            <Divider />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Link to codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cloud-f3v2lk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Here's what I think I should do to solve the problem:

- I need to get the array of `filteredOptions`, which in my case, when I type in `company` there should be an array of 5.
- if the `option` === the last item in `filterOptions` array, then there's no Divider added, like in the snippet below.

```
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <>
      <li {...props}>
        <StyledOptionBox>{option}</StyledOptionBox>
      </li>
      {option !== filteredOptions[filteredOptions.length - 1] && <Divider />}
    </>
  )}
```

But after reading the MUI documentation I still can't figure out where to get the array of filtered options. Any idea?

Or is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance I couldnt see any easy way to accomplish this, you either have to create a customized hook with [useAutocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete) or using [filteroptions](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#createfilteroptions-config-filteroptions) another option perhaps not ideal would be simply in your render option pushing the values to higher scoped variable.

For example:

Define a variable outside your return

```
let filteredOptions = [];
```

And inside your autocomplete

```
renderOption={(props, option) => {
   filteredOptions.push(option)
return (
    <>
      <li {...props}>
        <StyledOptionBox>{option}</StyledOptionBox>
      </li>
      {option !== filteredOptions[filteredOptions.length - 1] && <Divider />}
    </>
  )}}
```

Working sample:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Autocomplete, TextField, Box, Divider } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& label, & label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "green"
  }
});

const StyledOptionBox = styled(Box)({
  color: "green"
});

const options = [
  "Company ABC",
  "Company BCD",
  "Company CDE",
  "Company DEF",
  "Company EFG",
  "Corporate ABC",
  "Corporate BCD",
  "Corporate CDE",
  "Corporate DEF",
  "Corporate EFG"
];
export default function App() {
  let filteredOptions = []
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
      
        renderInput={(params) => {
          filteredOptions = []
          return (
          <StyledTextField
            {...params}
            label="Search your company here"
            variant="outlined"
          />
        )}}
        renderOption={(props, option) => {
          filteredOptions.push(option)
          console.log(filteredOptions) 
          return(
          <>
            <li {...props}>
              <StyledOptionBox>{option}</StyledOptionBox>
            </li>
            <Divider />
          </>
        )}}
      />

    </div>
  );
}
```